# Angular module not available

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I cannot load the main module of my Angular website. I get no errors on gulp, but try to open the website I can see this on the console.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myproject-ui' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Where should I be looking at for this error?
The `var myApp = angular.module('myproject-ui', [])` looks correct.

Comment: Please share your controller and html codes

Comment: look on the positions of your files loading, angular should be the first, your app declaration the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look for places using your module `angular.module('myproject-ui')` before you have declared your module `angular.module('myproject-ui', [])`

Make sure that the script file declaring your module is included on the page before any scripts that use it.